# Error in Logger.js ( info (...msgs) ) while executing "webdriver-manager update" command

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Iam getting the below error while running the webdriver-manager update command . Below is the error as displayed on console.

```
I am using the below versions for your reference 
npm version - 2.5.11
protractor - 5.3.1

Console Ouput
==============
C:\Users\XXXXXXXX>webdriver-manager update
webdriver-manager: using global installed version 12.0.6
C:\Users\XXXXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webdriver-manager\built\lib\c
li\logger.js:67
    info(...msgs) {
         ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)

Please advise on this issue.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your nodejs to like nodejs 8.x